# What does a "JMES path query" look like when saving a variable in Tavern?

Tags: yaml, jmespath, tavern

In my Tavern test file, I save a variable like so:

```
[...]
save:
  headers:
    csrf: x-csrf-token
[...]
```

When I run pytest, it logs this warning:

```
tavern/util/dict_util.py:119: FutureWarning: In a future version of Tavern, selecting for values to save in nested objects will have to be done as a JMES path query - see http://jmespath.org/ for more information
```

[JMESPath.org](http://jmespath.org/) isn't of much help, and neither is [Tavern's documentation](https://tavern.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#response). The 'x-csrf-token' field is not nested inside 'headers', so I don't understand the warning. I've tried two different JMES-like-syntaxes, but both give me "cant find key" errors instead:

```
save:
  csrf: headers.x-csrf-token

save:
  headers:
    csrf: headers.x-csrf-token
```

What exactly is Tavern expecting here?

Answer (score 1):

JMESPath unquoted identifiers cannot contain hyphens. You can use a [quoted identifier](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#identifiers) instead. Try:

```
save:
  headers:
    csrf: '"x-csrf-token"'
```

The single quotes are needed to tell YAML that the double-quotes are part of the string. The double quotes in JMESPath allow you to include characters that would otherwise be allowed in an identifier, such as hyphens.